# I would like to populate a entry in config file at run time via docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have tomcat installed in a container, inside it there is application configuration file. I would like to populate a value inside it during run time. (before that I dont know what the value so cant populate at the time of building the image)

I am invoking service with docker-compose up, and I would like the value in configuration file gets replaced via the value I provide to docker compose as parameter

something like docker-compose up -e "value at run time via docker compose"

```
 URL for server
 SERVERADD=https://{{value at run time via docker compose}}/{{index}}
```

Can I accomplish this with environment variable or any other way kindly suggest !!!

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done in an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) or [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) script that is built into the image.

The script checks for the environment variable, does the replacements or other work required, then continues on to run the command as before.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$SOME_ENV" ]; then
  sed -i '' -e 's/^param=.*/param='"$SOME_ENV"'/' /etc/file.conf
fi
exec "$@"
```

The script needs to be added to an image, the Dockerfile could be:

```
FROM whatever
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "run_server", "-o", "option" ]
```

Comment: Is this still considered the best way to modify config files with Docker/Compose? In my case, the prod environment will be AWS ECS/Fargate with AWS RDS and S3, while the dev environment uses non-containerized MySQL and local storage. I think this is the missing link I needed to modify config files in both envirronments. Thanks